# Error while testing Assert statement in Xilinx

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, xilinx-ise

I'm currently recieving this error

> ERROR:HDLCompiler:1731 -
>   Line ...: found '0' definitions of operator "=", cannot determine
>   exact overloaded matching definition for "="

for my last 2 Assert statements shown below (PulseOutput and IsCounting).  It doesn't like that equals sign, buth how do you test for a 1 bit signal value? The assert above it (CountTemp) receives no errors. any idea?!

```
signal CountTemp : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal PulseOutput  : std_logic;
signal IsCounting  : std_logic;
--------------------------------------------------------------
stim_proc:process
begin       
    SystemClear <= '1';
   -- hold reset state for 10 ns, then test 3 signals, then hold for additional 10 ns
   wait for 10 ns;
    assert (CountTemp = X"0000") report "CountTemp should equal 0 when System Clear is active" severity ERROR;
    assert (PulseOutput = 0) report "PulseOutput should equal 0 when System Clear is active" severity ERROR;    
    assert (IsCounting = 0) report "IsCounting should equal 0 when System Clear is active" severity ERROR;  
    wait for 10 ns;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std_logic` bits are represented with apostrophe `'` around them, note that this is also called a *tick* in VHDL.  So for example in your code:

```
stim_proc:process
begin       
    SystemClear <= '1';
   -- hold reset state for 10 ns, then test 3 signals, then hold for additional 10 ns
   wait for 10 ns;
    assert (CountTemp = X"0000") report "CountTemp should equal 0 when System Clear is active" severity ERROR;
    assert (PulseOutput = '0') report "PulseOutput should equal 0 when System Clear is active" severity ERROR;    
    assert (IsCounting = '0') report "IsCounting should equal 0 when System Clear is active" severity ERROR;  
    wait for 10 ns;
```

Comment: `'` is referred to as Apostrophe or tick in the standard. An asterisk is the `*` character.